# $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^n+(\pi /3)^n}{x^{n-1} + (\pi/ 3)^{n-1}}$, where n is an even integer. Find $f(x)$

Tags: limits

The logic is applied is that for $|x|<1$, $x^{\infty}=0$, so $f(x)=\pi/3$

For $|x|>1$, taking $x^n$ common gives $f(x)=x$

Now in the first expression, if we take $(\pi/3)^n$ common we get $f(x)=\pi/3$ for any value $|x|<\pi/3$

So which one is correct, $|x|<1$ or $|x|<\pi/3$?

Comment: For $1\lt x\lt \pi/3$ , $ (\pi/3)^n$ dominates $x^n$, so $ |x|\lt \pi/3$ is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^n+(\pi /3)^n}{x^{n-1} + (\pi/ 3)^{n-1}}$$
$$g(y)=\frac{\pi}{3}\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{y^n+1}{y^{n-1} + 1}$$
where $\displaystyle y = \frac{3x}{\pi}$. Now, if $|y| < 1$, $y^n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. $|y| < 1$ iff $|x| < \pi/3$. Similarly you can solve for the case $|y| > 1$. $|y| > 1$ iff $|x| > \pi/3$.

One thing that you've missed stating is the case when $|x| = \pi/3$ or $|y| = 1$. The case is easy to miss, nevertheless trivial!